# Можно ли повесить в динамической ссылке, в popup окне ajax-form заблокировать кнопку?

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ссылка создана yf jQuery, нажав на которую открывается 
 в popup окне форма обратной связи mail.php, тоже создана с помощью jQuery, и есть у этой формы кнопка отправки формы. Я хотел ее заблокировать если форма не валидна. 
но блокируется вся ссылка и окно popup не работает.

```
var phones = document.querySelector("phones-' + e + '");
if (phones.length === 19) {
    $('#popup_submit').removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
    $('#popup_submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас несколько элементов с одним и тем же `id="popup_submit"`. Такой селектор `$('#popup_submit')` находит только первый из них. Дайте им разные `id`.

---

```
var phones = document.querySelector("phones-' + e + '");
```

Если Вы рассчитываете, что в выражение селектора попадет переменная `e`, то здесь напутано с кавычками.

---

```
if (phones.length === 19) {
```

Здесь Вы сравниваете несуществующее свойство DOM-элемента с числом. Вряд ли они когда-нибудь будут равны.

---

Не смешивайте в одном коде работу напрямую с элементами DOM и jQuery.

Comment: 2 и 3 да я согласен, сейчас изменю. А вот как я поменяю один id я затрудняюсь ответить. Объясните как можно это сделать. Если вас не затруднит.

Comment: @pips Сколько на странице элементов с `id="popup_submit"`?

Comment: один присвоен кнопке которую я хочу заблокировать.

Comment: @pips Точно? Пора показывать html.

Comment: Это интернет магазин, то есть каждый товар получается свое окно, и своя кнопка?? phones-' + e + '" точно так же искать?

Comment: @pips Я не знаю. Это же *Ваш* магазин :).  Сделайте маленький пример, который демонстрирует наблюдаемое поведение.

Comment: @pips Ссылка "править" - под вопросом. В редакторе вопроса - кнопка "Фрагмент кода".

Comment: @ Igor вы были правы id для кнопки разные на каждом item `
        '<input type="button" value="+" id="plus">\n' +
        '<input id="phones-' + e + '" class="form-control verify" type="tel" name="Телефон" placeholder="+38 (000) 000-00-00" \n' +
        'pattern="[\\+]\\d{2}\\s[\\(]\\d{3}[\\)]\\s\\d{3}[\\-]\\d{2}[\\-]\\d{2}" minlength="19" maxlength="19">\n' +
        '<span class="form__error">Введите в формате +38 (000) 000-00-00</span>\n' +
        '<button id="popup_submit-' + e + '" class="btn">Заказать</button>' +`

Comment: @pips Где здесь кнопка с `id="popup_submit"`?

Comment: в самом низу но уже я добавил туда счетчик

Comment: @pips Тогда я не понимаю, на какой вопрос я отвечаю.

Comment: Спасибо, я посмотрел и понял свою ошибку.

Comment: @pips Очень хорошо. Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.